# Hide checkboxes if they do not match input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Basically I have a list of check boxes like so

```
<label style='padding-right:30px;' >
<input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='1'> bob ;
<input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='2'> john ;
<input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='3'> mary ;
</label>
```

I also have a input box for user to type what checkbox to show

```
<input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Filter Tag Name" id="filter" >
```

What i want is when a user types bob, all check boxes without the text value of bob will be hidden.

I currently have a java script but it is matching the value of the checkbox not the text of it

JS as follows

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#filter').on('keyup', function() {
    var query = this.value;
    $('[name^="tag[]"]').each(function(i, elem) {
              if (elem.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1) {
                  $(this).parent().css('display', 'inline-block');
                  $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
              }else{
                  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
                  $(this).css('display', 'none');
              }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Surround your checkboxes with spans to easily extract their text
2. Use the `input` event which will fire whenever the input changes. This is better than `keyup` because `keyup` may fir when a `ctrl` button is clicked for example
3. Show the checkbox by default. Then check if its *trimmed* value contains the filter value. If not, then hide

```js
$('#filter').on('input', function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();
  var options = $('span:has(:checkbox)');
  options.each(function() {
    $(this).show();
    if ($(this).text().trim().indexOf(filter) < 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style='padding-right:30px;' >
<span><input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='1'> bob</span>
<span><input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='2'> john </span>
<span><input type='checkbox' name='tag[]' value='3'> mary </span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Filter Tag Name" id="filter" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , it works.
However could you elaborate more on why it would help to surround the check box with span?

Comment: @user3148070, because then you can check its text using `$(this).text()`

Comment: @user3148070, when you surround with a span, `text` will return the inner text which is what we are looking for